# New PCL project not building on Mac/Xamarin studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

We're trying to get our projects to build, which wasn't a problem until today.

We got a solution with multiple projects including Portable Class Library (PCL) projects. We've successfully built those before but our Macbook lost the capability to build those projects.

I get a total of 31 build errors for every PCL project:

```
- The predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported (CS0518)
- The predefined type 'System.ValueType' is not defined or imported (CS0518)
- The predefined type 'System.Attribute' is not defined or imported (CS0518)
- 28 more times the same error stating other basic classes like Int16, Int32, Double, Single, etc.
```

To see if this always happens, I've created a new solution with a new PCL project. Tried to compile that and I got the same errors there.
After checking the references, I see that they're all 'red'.

I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 but I also tried it in MonoDevelop. Both without success.

I can simply create a project in VS + Xamarin.iOS plugin and push that to the mac and it'll just run. But building on the Mac itself, doesn't work anymore.

Extra, possibly related info:

- We were developing on the Mac before. After extending out monotouch license, we downloaded the Xamarin.iOS plugin and continued development on a Windows machine.
- After extending the license, we also got the new updates for monotouch and Xamarin studio
- We didn't build directly on the Mac since extending the license.
- We decided to build directly on the Mac today, because we couldn't run the app on the actual device from Visual Studio.

Any possible solutions are welcome.

Comment: Have you checked what .net version you're using?

Comment: .NET 4 I'd expect a newly created PCL project to run without any modifications. And it did before.

Comment: The PCL functionality in the recent Xamarin.iOS is broken, see [here](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/xamarin-48-stable-not-sure.html). I am not aware of any fix being around the corner.

Comment: Update your Mono to 3.2.1 in the Beta channel.

Comment: That seemed to work. We updated to the beta channel and it started working again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version (3.2.0)

You can:

- use Visual Studio to build your PCL projects or
- switch to the alpha channel and upgrade to 3.2.1 alpha. Go to Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates > and set the update channel to Alpha. This includes a hotfix for 3.2.0 which I believe is regarding the broken PCL

## Update

Although the alpha build (3.2.1) is able to build a new PCL project but that's all about it. For me it fails to recognise many keywords and gives nonsense errors on my actual project. If I find a fix I'll post it here.

Comment: The alpha channel works fine here! Builds and runs. The thing is, we have released an app before with the an older stable build. Looks like they broke it in the newer version or something...

Answer (score 0):

I have installed 3.2.1 build, it seems fixed PCL issue, but I keep getting "Are you missing `System.Xml.Linq' assembly reference?" issue.